# SVN client too old after I used sshfs

Tags: svn

I have a svn checked out web application on a shared hosting linux server.  The linux server has an svn client that I can access via ssh.

From my localhost, I did the following

```
> sshfs myusername@sharedhostingserver.com:webappdir/ /media/webapp
> cd /media/webapp
> svn update
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
> svn clean up
```

It's been 15 minutes and the svn clean up still isn't finished. I think it may have froze.  So then I did the following:

```
> ssh myusername@sharedhostingserver.com
> cd webappdir
> svn update
svn: This client is too old to work with working copy '.'; please get a newer Subversion client
```

So now I can't update my webappdir because my /media/webapp is stuck on svn clean up, and my shared hosting server's svn client is out of date.  I don't have privileges to install a new svn client on the shared hosting server.

How do I get my svn update to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The working copy format has been upgraded. This means that 1.4 and older Subversion clients will not be able to work with working copies produced by Subversion 1.5. Working copies are upgraded automatically."

http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.5_releasenotes.html

Comment: Does this mean I'll need to set up a separate checkout under a 1.5 version of svn, then do a manual merge of all files I've modified?  I've modified so many files, and the repository has so many updates, doing a manual merge will take a long time. Any easier way around this?

Comment: Either upgrade the old svn client, so it can read the new working copy - or wipe the working copy and perform a new checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Apache provide a script that downgrades your working copy to an earlier format, in order to restore compatibility with older clients. See this FAQ entry: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change